# Mercurial plugin not available?

Tags: plugins, mercurial, scmmanager

After install new version(2.0.0) of scm-manager I saw only 2 version control Git and subversion in the combobox when I create new repository.
in the old version (1.6) I can set the Mercurial via setting but now I can't see any setting about Mercurial.
is the Mercurial deprecated in the new version? if not how to set it?

only scm-server not detect the Mercurial but if you get scm-webapp from scm-server and run under tomcat, it detect the Mercurial and you can see in the combobox when you create new repository.

Comment: Git|Mercurial|Subversion supported in the core according to docs. Maybe you have to have client of HG?

Comment: I have on windows 10 : 
-> python-2.7.18.amd64 
-> mercurial-4.9.1.win-amd64-py2.7
-> tortoisehg-5.0.2-x64
but Mercurial still not detected in the scm-manager

Answer (score 1):

finally, i found the solution, I must set manually, after the scm-server start,

go to -> Administration -> Setting -> Mercurial and set the values of two fields:

1. HG Binary: set to mercurial folder installed (e.g `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe`)
2. Python Binary: set to python 2.7 folder (e.g `C:\Python27\python.exe`)

I don't know why scm-server not detect Mercurial and scm-webapp detect it !!